# Rails 4.1 + Sunspot: unable to find scope Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollectionPolicy::Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I am trying to setup search in my Rails 4.1 app using the `sunspot` gem. I have a model called Post which adds the `searchable` block

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :description, :body
  end
end
```

I am then performing a search in my controller

```
def search
  if params[:search]
    @search = policy_scope(Post).search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @posts = @search.results
    render :index unless @posts.empty?
    flash[:error] = "No results found"
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end
```

I receive the following error

```
unable to find scope Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollectionPolicy::Scope ...
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please create app/policies/paginated_collection_policy.rb:

```
class Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollectionPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

Note: Both module Sunspot and module Search have been created in gem Sunspot. Since both Ruby modules and classes are open (appendable), no need to recreate them. Just append the needed Pundit policy class.